# QGIS multiple layer selection

Tags: qgis

i have tried using the 'Multiple Layer Selection' plugin but it only offers the selection in triangle .. is there a way to have the same effect but with a polygon instead ?

Answer (score 3):

It has multiple selection by rectangle, as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: yes i'm aware.. what i'm looking for is doing the selection in polygons, since no area is shaped in a perfect rectangle @ahmadhanb

Comment: @AbdullahAlaa You need to be clear in your question, as you mentioned triangle. Anyway, the answer is NO. You have two options selection by point, and select by rectangle. The plugin does not support selection by polygon.